# How to make a TeamCity build fail (timeout) if it takes too long?

Tags: teamcity

How do we put a timeout on a TeamCity build?

We have a TeamCity build which runs some integration tests. These tests read/write data to a database and sometimes this is very slow (why it is slow is another open quesiton).

We currently have timeouts in our integration tests to check that e.g. the data has been written within 30 seconds, but these tests are randomly failing during periods of heavy use.

If we removed the timeouts from the tests, we would want to fail the build only if the entire run took more than some much larger timeout.

But I can't see how to do that.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

On the first page of the build setup you will find the field highlights in my screenie - use that[image]

Comment: In the TC 7 the option is moved to the "Build Failure Conditions" section

Comment: In TeamCity Enterprise 2017.1.2 it is in "Failure Conditions" section

Comment: Yes this option has been moved to a different page see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8339668/how-to-make-a-teamcity-build-fail-timeout-if-it-takes-too-long/50723919#50723919

Answer (score 24):

In TeamCity v.9 and v.10 you should find it under the "Failure Conditions". See:

[image]